# Create excel from a text file using Python to have alternate rows as Column header and values

Tags: python, bash

I've a data in the below format. Now I want to write a Python program which will take the line ending with "+" as column header and the rest should go as the column value to an excel file. Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve that? I want this in Excel format so that I can do more text formatting.

input.txt

```
Name+
AAAA
Age+
13
Gender+
Male
Address+
Name+
BBBB
Gender+
Male
Address+
23, Canada
Name+
CCCC
Age+
14
Address+
23, Germany
Name+
DDDD
Age+
13
Gender+
Male
Address+
23, Brazil
```

[The output should like in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeFUp.jpg)

Comment: What did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Just use an excel manipulator library like `Openpyxl` or `Xlswriter`. If you are doing so and are stuck, show us your code. Don't ask us to write it for you!

Comment: Sure. I'm trying that. Will update you with my output and code.